# What pay-for hosting is great for ASP.Net sites?

Tags: hosting, asp.net

I'm making a portfolio site and I want it to be **pay for**, NOT FREE.

I need ease of use and good costumer service. Which site has a proven track record.

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions. In future edit the existing question and flagged it to be re-opened. Also please don't use descriptive words in your posts, this will get your account suspended.

Comment: I can't flag for re-open because I'm not high enough level. Please don't close questions claiming duplicates when they are clearly not.

Answer (score 3):

There are a bunch of options out there, but many people seem to like [DiscountASP.nET](http://discountasp.net/). However, rather than regurgitating what others have said...

stackoverflow questions

- [ASP.NET hosting options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305/asp-net-hosting-options)
- [Recommend ASP.NET 3.5 SP1 Hosting Providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377008/recommend-asp-net-3-5-sp1-hosting-providers)
- [Can you recommend good hosts for ASP.NET? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503929/can-you-recommend-good-hosts-for-asp-net-closed) (this one links to pretty much every dupe on SO)

serverfault questions

- [Asp.net 3.5, IIS7 and SQL Server 2008 Hosting recommendations](https://serverfault.com/questions/54070/asp-net-3-5-iis7-and-sql-server-2008-hosting-recommendations)
- [Hosting my ASP.NET website - ANY recommendations?](https://serverfault.com/questions/11796/hosting-my-asp-net-website-any-recommendations)